# How can I change the function being used depending on whether value in an array is positive or not in R

Tags: r, arrays, if-statement

I have an array (Tw) of this size: 2160 x 1080 x 12

```
Tw=array(-10:10, c(2160,1080,12))
```

I also have a temperature array (Ta)

```
Ta=array(-40:40, c(2160,1080,12))
```

I want to apply a slightly different function to Ta, depending on whether Tw>=0 or Tw <0.

```
t.es <- function(T) 6.107 * exp(17.38 * T/(239. + T))    # Tw >= 0
```

Or

```
t.es <- function(T) 6.107 * exp(22.44 * T/(272.4 + T))    # Tw <= 0
```

I tried using an if statement, but it doesn't appear to be working...it seems to just be applying one of the functions:

```
if(Tw>=0){
  t.es <- function(T) 6.107 * exp(17.38 * T/(239. + T))    # Tw >= 0 
  es <- t.es(Ta) 
}else{
  t.es <- function(T) 6.107 * exp(22.44 * T/(272.4 + T))    # Tw <= 0
  es<- t.es(Ta) 
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `if` I would suggest to make use of a vectorized `ifelse`.

To make the example more minimal I reduced the size of your arrays and make use of two simplified functions which make it easy to check that the approach works as desired:

```r
t.es1 <- function(T) 0
t.es2 <- function(T) 1

Tw <- array(-10:10, c(2, 3, 4))
Ta <- array(-40:40, c(2, 3, 4))

foo <- ifelse(Tw >= 0, t.es1(Ta), t.es2(Ta))

foo
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    1
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    0
#> [2,]    1    1    0
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 4
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    1
#> [2,]    0    1    1
```

A second option to achieve your desired result would be:

```
bar <- array(dim = dim(Tw))

bar[Tw >= 0] <- t.es1(Ta[Tw >= 0])
bar[Tw < 0] <- t.es2(Ta[Tw < 0])

identical(foo, bar)
#> [1] TRUE
```